# Issues with Intellisense and class library

Tags: c#

I am using Visual Studio 2013. I am trying to start unit testing by using [this tutorial](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/981/unit-testing-aspnet-mvc-nunit-visual-studio).

I have added a class library and a reference to MVC. However, the Intellisense/Autocompletion is not working properly within my class library. Currently, this is all the code I have in my test class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NUnit.Framework;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web;
using Application_Portal;
using Application_Portal.Controllers;

namespace ApplicationPortalTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class HomeControllerTest
    {
        HomeController home = new HomeController();
    }
}
```

The Intellisense does not seem to recognize the home variable (no suggested properties, etc.) Typing home.Index() gives the following error:

```
ApplicationPortalTests.HomeControllerTest.home' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'
```

Furthermore, it does not even seem to recognize "var" (as in var result = ...). Instead, when I type var and hit space, it autocompletes it as         EnvironmentVariableTarget.

I have tried cleaning and rebuilding the project, and closing and reopening Visual Studio, but with no success.

What might the issue be? I appreciate any advice.

Comment: Did you create a method or are you writing in the class directly?

Comment: You can't refer to field properties at the class level.  Same with the `var` keyword.  At the class level you can only have properties, fields, constructors and methods.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to write code that isn't inside a method.  You can't do that in C#.

Comment: You are absolutely right.  I forget to actually add the test method! Completely a careless mistake on my part. Thanks.

Comment: I have removed the VS tags since this is a coding issue rather than an issue with the IDE.

Comment: @KellyMarchewa if it helps any, i've been coding for ~20 years and occasionally I still make this mistake.  "What?  why wont this work?  Oh, not in a method.  right"  Sometimes contextual awareness has to catch up, or smth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared your variable inside the class. If you want to use this variable, it must be within the context of a member. For instance:

```
[Test]
public void test_my_index_page()
{
     var result = home.index();
}
```